# linux bash count size of files in folder

Tags: linux, bash

i saw a few posts in forum but i cant manage to make them work for me

i have a script that runs in a folder and i want it to count the size only of the files in that folder but without the folders inside.

so if i have

```
file1.txt
folder1
file2.txt
```

it will return the size in bytes of file1+file2 without folder1

`find . -maxdepth 1 -type f` 
gives me a list of all the files i want to count but how can i get the size of all this files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tool for this is `xargs`:

```
find "$dir" -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0 | xargs -0 wc -c
```

Note that `find -print0` and `xargs -0` are GNU extensions, but if you know they are available, they are well worth using in your script - you don't know what characters might be present in the filenames in the target directory.

You will need to post-process the output of `wc`; alternatively, use `cat` to give it a single input stream, like this:

```
find "$dir" -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0 | xargs -0 cat | wc -c
```

That gives you a single number you can use in following commands.

(I've assumed you meant "size" in *bytes*; obviously substitute `wc -m` if you meant *characters* or `wc -l` if you meant *lines*).

Comment: thanks this works, the size tho, it will alwayse be bytes?

Comment: @Dino - see my last sentence: you can tell `wc` what to count: bytes, characters or lines.  There's no point me reproducing its man page, as you can just read that yourself!

Comment: If you are using GNU find why not just use that to print the size `find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf '%s\t%p\n'`

Comment: @123, that will print a size for each file - you'll need to sum the values externally if you do that.  Of course, without seeing the rest of the script, we're just guessing what the result will be used for...

Comment: thanks alot, this is the script im using    
'find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0 | xargs -0 cat | wc -c' 
is there a way to exclude a file named test.sh from this scrip? so it doesnt count file named test.sh?

Comment: Yes, you could simply `grep -Fvxz test.sh` between the `find` and the `xargs` (read the man page if you don't recognize all the options).